# swlist command to get software installed on different system

Tags: perl, hp-ux

When you run swlist with no arguments on an HPUX system you get the packages that are installed on that particular host.  I want that same output but instead listing packages that are installed on a different system.

Is this possible?

Comment: Wait. Do you mean how do you find Perl packages installed on your system? Or do you mean how do you find software packages on a system other than HPUX (and maybe using Perl to do that)? Cause I thought you were talking about the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find $(perl -e 'print"@INC"') -name \*.pm
```

will get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Net::SSH::Expect to execute the swlist command on the remote host, grab the output and do what you want with it.  That's what I would do.